# Injection using an InjectionToken?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, stackblitz

Attempting to inject an object using an `InjectionToken`.

In the `AppModule` I have:

```
    export const tokenConfigKey = new InjectionToken('config');

    const tokenBasedConfig = {
        provide: tokenConfigKey,
        useValue: {
          key: 'value'
      }
    }
```

And in the `AppComponent`:

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template:`<h1>Hello Angular Lovers!</h1>`
    })
    export class AppComponent  {
      constructor(@Inject('config') config,
                  @Inject(tokenConfigKey) configByToken) {
      }
    }
```

[This is a complete stacblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-configuration-injection?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Injection using the string key is passing, but injection with the token is failing.  Any ideas why?

### Article

[Here's an article in case anyone wants to play with this](https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/design-time-external-component-configuration-48dcbd314712)

Comment: Are you using the same instance of the injection token?  In other words, do you have something like... `import { tokenConfigKey } from '/path/to/app.module'`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A circular dependency issue could exist due to the fact that the `AppModule` imports the `AppComponent` and the `AppComponent` imports the InjectionToken from the `AppModule`.

Moving token to separate resolvs the issue:

**token.ts**

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
export const BASE_URL = new InjectionToken<string>('BaseUrl');
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [{ provide: BASE_URL, useValue: { key: 'http://localhost' } }],
```

**app.component.ts**

```
 constructor(@Inject(BASE_URL) configByToken) {
    console.log(configByToken);
  }
```

Comment: This is the updated stackblitz in case anyone wants to see: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-configuration-injection2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I moved the InjectionToken to the `AppComponent` and exported it from there that way there are only two files and no circular dependency.